# How do I go to Checkout Page without product in cart?

Tags: commerce

I am using [Commerce Donate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) and configured it to show donation form on checkout page. That is what actually I need. Donation form, contact info and payment form on same page.

But we cannot go to the checkout page without having some product in cart.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please follow next article: [Express checkout with Drupal Commerce](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/express-checkout-drupal-commerce)<br/><br/>
Also you can use sandbox projects: 1. [Commerce Single Page Checkout](https://drupal.org/sandbox/rj/1886778) 2. [Commerce Single Page](https://drupal.org/sandbox/tmsimont/1891418) 3. [Commerce Checkout Complete Page](https://drupal.org/sandbox/drugan/2111003)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following code to a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Alter the default checkout callback to allow checkout without products.
  $items['checkout']['page callback'] = 'YOURMODULE_checkout_router';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_order_can_checkout().
 */
function YOURMODULE_commerce_checkout_order_can_checkout($order) {
  return TRUE;
}

/**
 * Displays the checkout form and create the user a cart if none exist.
 */
function YOURMODULE_checkout_router() {
  global $user;
  // Load the shopping cart order.
  if (!($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid))) {
    $order = commerce_cart_order_new();
  }
  drupal_goto('checkout/' . $order->order_id);
}
```